# Intel compiler 2018 syntax change

Tags: c++, intel, icc, intel-parallel-studio, intel-composer

I'm evaluating IC 2018, while normally working with IC 2016 & MSVC & CLANG. IC 2018 seems not to cope with several things.

First it doesn't like _Pragma, for instance:

```
_Pragma("forceinline recursive")
```

I need that to support multiple compilers like this:

```
#define MFORCEINLINE    _Pragma("forceinline recursive")
```

Then it also fails with the keyword restrict (previously used by IC), but it seems that __restrict may work. After the gazillion keywords I gave up. Am I doing something wrong? Mainly with the pragmas, I use a lot of those for various optimization specifications.

Comment: IDK what "recursive" does, but ICC implements GNU C/C++ extensions, [including function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes), so try `__attribute__((always_inline)) int foo(int bar) { ...; }` to force a function to inline even when compiling without optimization.

Comment: And yes, in C++ you should be using `__restrict`.  I think it's supported across gcc/clang/icc/msvc.  I'm surprised any compilers allowed the C99 `restrict` keyword in C++ mode.  Or were you compiling as C before?

Comment: Thanks for the info! It's just that it was different before, so I thought "maybe I missed some option or something". Anyways thanks for the __attribute__((always_inline)) idea, didn't know it could work on Windows as well.